# Is it a good practice allowing the possibility of echoing a NULL value?

Tags: php

So I'm trying to save input values from a form in case the page reloads and I'm setting the initial value at the start of the script like like so:

```
$username = "";
$password = "";
$password_confirmation = "";
$email = "";
$email_confirmation = ""; 
$business_name = "";
```

Then if the form has been submitted and the server request method has been set to "POST" I set every individual variable to its corresponding value like so:

```
$username= filter_input(INPUT_POST, "username", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
etc...
```

Then on each input element I'm echoing the corresponding value:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
```

So my question is, if for some reason filter_input fails and returns a NULL value and if I echo that NULL value will I have any trouble?

Comment: It will just print nothing, the problem is, you are outputting the data without sanitizing it, you should use `htmlspecialchars` to output the data

Comment: Just try to add nothing and see what happens.

Comment: In PHP `null` is converted to empty string on echoing.

Comment: You shouldn't be saving data if it is NULL to begin with, if it is a username, e-mail address, or password. Reject it and make the user resubmit. Your database will reject it anyway if it is set up properly.

Comment: @MehdiBounya That's true thanks for that observation

Comment: @GaryHayes I forgot to mention I already have checks for those in my script, as for what you said about my database rejecting data do you have any good resources for configuring that, I'm fairly new to SQL as well so I'm using MySQL and phpMyAdmin to configure the database

Comment: Well, if you set up a primary key, it cannot be NULL, If you set a column to be unique, it also cannot be NULL, and you should be able to just check a box in phpMyAdmin to explicitly state "Not Null". You can set the username field to be primary key, which restricts usernames to be unique and not null, and set the email address field to be unique, so multiple accounts cannot use the same email address. ( spam bots love to use the same ones over and over, and will flood your database with bogus accounts ) Be sure to add a boolean field for validated email addresses, so only they can use site.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a ternary method to get the value of the page on reload.

Sample:

your code

View index page

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

If you want to reload the value of the textbox after you submit you dont need to place a null value, instead check if the textbox has been posted or not. You can do this,

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
       <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php isset($_POST["username"]) ? echo $username : echo ""; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

it means if the username has been posted, it already exist so it is set, therefore you will re take the value, else it will just display an empty box.

Hope this help for cleaner and more efficient coding.

Comment: there's a shorter way in PHP7 to do that sort of check, and it is `$_POST['username'] ?? ''; // two single quotes.`